# T-SQL - Dense_Rank returning strange numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dense-rank

The following Dense_Rank query returns very strange output:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ColC ORDER BY ColB) AS [Rank]
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           concat(ColA, CONVERT(DATE, ColB)) AS ColC
    FROM ##Table
) Subquery1;
```

Returns:

```
ColB                ColC   Rank
01/11/2017 14:06    ValueA  3
01/11/2017 16:06    ValueA  5
01/11/2017 16:09    ValueA  6
01/11/2017 16:17    ValueA  7
02/11/2017 12:19    ValueB  2
02/11/2017 16:00    ValueB  5
02/11/2017 16:09    ValueB  6
02/11/2017 16:19    ValueB  7
02/11/2017 16:28    ValueB  8
02/11/2017 16:37    ValueB  9
```

The relative ranking appears to be correct, but the numbers assigned to each rank are weird.  Why no number 1, 2 or 4 for Value A?  Why are numbers 1, 3 and 4 missed for Value B?

Comment: The query you pasted is not what generated that output (at least not that _exact_ output).  Please show us the actual query, along with sample input data and the current/expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the actual query, but I'm pretty sure, that your observation is somehow related to this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, RankingValue INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1),(2),(3),(8),(3),(2),(9),(0);
```

--This query applies a WHERE-filter **before** the Ranking

```
SELECT *
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY RankingValue) AS TheRank
FROM @tbl
WHERE RankingValue>3;
```

--The result

```
ID  RankingValue    TheRank
4   8               1
7   9               2
```

--This query applies the filter **later**

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY RankingValue) AS TheRank
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE RankingValue>3;
```

--The result

```
ID  RankingValue    TheRank
4   8               5        <-- Your weird values... ??
7   9               6
```